# Модель MVC Ошибка в файле config.php

Tags: php

Добрый день. Я создаю модель MVC и в файле config.php выдаёт ошибку

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:/wamp64/www/Model.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\mvc2\conf\config.php on line 10.

Все файлы в соответствующих директориях присутствуют. Может кто из знающих поможет? Заранее спасибо

```
define("ROOT", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define("CONTROLLER_PATH", ROOT. "/controllers/");
define("MODEL_PATH", ROOT. "/models/");
define("VIEW_PATH", ROOT. "/views/");

require_once("db.php");
require_once("route.php");
require_once MODEL_PATH. 'Model.php';
require_once VIEW_PATH. 'View.php';
require_once CONTROLLER_PATH. 'Controller.php';


Routing::buildRoute();
```

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'C:/wamp64/www/Model.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\mvc2\conf\config.php on line 10

написано, какой файл функция не может подключить: `C:/wamp64/www/Model.php`. В этом пути нет директории `"/models/"`

Проверьте что находится в константе `MODEL_PATH`

Comment: В константе MODEL_PATH находится C:/wamp64/www/models/